# Javascript String Replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string of tags delimited by semicolons:

```
"red; yellow; blue; green; purple"
```

I would like to strip out all the tags that do not match a substring (case-insensitive.)

For example, if I have a substring "Bl" I would like to return "blue".

Any suggestions as how to best accomplish this in javascript?  Specifically, I'm wondering if there is a one-step method for doing this in regex...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What should the return type be? A semicolon delimited string or an array?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified.  Another semi-colon delimited string, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
var needle = 'blu';
var s = 'red; yellow; blue; geen; purple';
var a = s.split('; ');
var newArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].indexOf(needle) != -1) {
        newArray.push(a[i]);
    }
}
var result = newArray.join('; ');
alert(result);
```

The method is basically as Simon described, with one extra step - a `join` at the end to convert the result back to a string.

Just for fun, here's a crazy regex based solution. Warning: if your search term contans special characters they will need to be escaped. I'm assuming that the search term will contain only non-special characters:

```
var s = 'red; yellow; blue; geen; purple';
var result = ('; ' + s).replace(/;(?![^;]*blu)[^;]*(?=;|$)/g, '').substring(2);
alert(result);
```

Comment: +1 beat me to the regexp version although i used a function as the replacement string which copied the matches to another string..

Comment: That is indeed a crazy regex. :) Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I believe the regex could be simplified to: `(^|\b)\w*blu\w*(; |$)`

Answer (score 2):

First parse the string to an array using [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)(), after that iterate over the array and look for matches using [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) or [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) on the items in the array. If you want to check case-insensitive you can either use a case insensitive regexp in match, or do toLowerCase on all elements being compared.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I'm doing something similar to that now.  I guess I was hoping there might be a one-step magical way to do it in regex.  :)

Comment: @travis: If you really want a crazy regex one-liner, see my answer - I've added a method that uses regex. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function find_substring(tags, search){
 var tags_array = tags.split(";");
 var found_tags = [];
 for(var i=0; i<tags_array.length; i++){
  if(tags_array[i].indexOf(search) > -1){
    found_tags.push(tags_array[i]);
  }
 }
 if(found_tags.length > 0){
  return found_tags.join("; ");
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}

var tags = "red; yellow; blue; geen; purple";
var search = "blue";
find_substring(tags,search);
```

Comment: Uhh, I don't think you want your for-loop to just return the tag element. Don't you want to build a new list of tags, and return that?